# How to generate compile_commands.json with QT project?

Tags: qt, clang

I'm not familiar with QT but have to work with a QT project(`.pro`) recently. I hope to generate a `compile_commands.json` for this project, so I can read codes inside emacs's lsp mode. Unfortunately, I cannot find any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Build/Generate Compilation Database` for "yourprojectname"

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a bit on your answer?

Comment: @Richard-Degenne `Build/Generate Compilation Database` is the menu of QTcreator

Comment: My qtcreator doesn't have that menu item. Is there a command line tool to do it?

Comment: What's your qtcreator version? I haven't heard of any cli tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

Bear is a tool to generate a `compile_commands.json` file by recording a complete build.

For a make-based build, you can run `make clean; bear -- make` to generate the file (and run a clean build!).